# Viewengine not looking into areas for views in asp.net mvc3 upgrade?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewengine, asp.net-mvc-migration

i'm upgrading my asp.net mvc app to the MVC 3 from mvc 2. I had everything set up so that there were no areas, but now i have to move the old application into its own area so i can start a new one. The new area is working great, but for some reason, when i try to go into the area where the old app was, it looks for the views to be in the views folder in the root of the app, instead of in the views folder in the area. any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out my issue was because the initial route registrations i was using were from the static routetable collection, instead of the context object passed into the area registration.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into an issue that I described in more detail in the following post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/14/mvc-areas-and-multiple-view-engines.aspx

Comment: not sure if the problem is related, its not a search order issue so much as its not even looking for the view in the area. like, i don't see any entries for the area in the paths searched error.

for instance, my new area is called Foo, i moved everything from the old structure in the root of the project into foo, ie, all of my default controllers/views/etc were moved into the Foo area. i register the area, but when i try to hit a route that's in the area, it only looks in the default views folders, and not the area's views folder.